# java vm stderr Failed to initialize in AIX

Tags: memory-management, jvm, heap-memory

when I typed java -Xms2M in AIX ,but I got  this kind information , the java version is IBM java 1.6.0
        **JVMJ9GC020E -Xms too large for heap

         JVMJ9VM015W Initialization error for library j9gc24(2): Failed to initialize
         Could not create the Java virtual machine.**
I am sure the machine has enough memory, it has 63232MB , so I don't know how to fix it. who know how to fix it ? Thank you .George

Answer (score 0):

we missed some system environment properties ,so it caused this error. now it fixed .

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more in case people have the same problem in the future and find your answer.